# Is it possible to calculate sine by hand?

Tags: trigonometry

Without a calculator, how can I calculate the sine of an angle, for example 32(without drawing a triangle)?

Comment: Convert $32^{\circ}$ to radian then, use Taylor expansion in the nearest known sine, say $30^{\circ} = \pi/6$.

Comment: maybe, we can predict approximate values, from the nearest known value. that is, $sin(30\circ) $ is 0.5. probably we can guess 0.52

Comment: @Vijay Raghavan: But how does a calculator find the exact value?

Comment: @Runemoro This is how `C` does it: http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_sin.c;hb=HEAD involving some iterative process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use first order approximation $\sin(x+h)=\sin(x)+\sin'(x)h=\sin(x)+\cos(x)h$

where $x$ is the point nearest to $x+h$ at which you already know the value of the $\sin$ function and its derivative $\cos$ function too.

Like for $\sin(32^0)=\sin(30^0)+\cos(30^0)*(\frac{\pi}{90})$

Here you need to take $h$ in radians which is $\frac{\pi}{90}$ for $(32^0-30^0)=2^0$

Answer (score 7):

Using Taylor expansion you get an approximation up to the desired precision

Comment: [wikipedia for the lazy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions)

Comment: I don't know why OP accepts this answer, but apparently MacLaurin series approximation doesn't work well when the angle is large, say $438748327^{\circ}$. Avatar's answer is much better than this one in terms of MSE standards.

Comment: What about $2\pi$-periodicity? The expansion is for radiant value.

Comment: @Lano My point is, expansion using terms $x - x^3/3! + \cdots$ doesn't work well unless $x\ll 1$. Otherwise you have to wait $(n+1)!$ to majorize $x^{n+1}$ in the error term, which normally results computation of many terms. If you use known sine values like $\sin(\pi/24)$, you could use first order approximation(two terms in Taylor) like in Avatar's answer.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao I think Taylor's series is actually better answer. We could always mod the angle to 360 so it should not be the problem